# Struct, pointers, getting the field value by the pointer

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I have something similar to this code in my application:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct STH
{
  double *buff;
  int size;
}STH;

void fun1(STH *s)
{
  fun3(s->buff, s->size);
}

void fun3(double *buff, int n)
{
  int i = 0;
  printf("N = %d\n", n);
  for(i=0; i<n; i++)
     printf("%d\n", buff[i]);
}

void fun2()
{
  STH s;

  s.size = 4;
  s.buff = malloc(sizeof(double) * s.size);

  fun1(&s);
}

int main()
{
    fun2();
    return 0;
}
```

When I try to print out the buffer in `fun3`, `gdb` says that there is an error in `fun3`. When I try to print out (in `fun2`) the value of the `s->size`, there is an error (instead of 4 it prints out strange numbers ....)

Comment: "%f\n" , s.buff = calloc(s.size, sizeof(double))

Comment: fun3(..){..} before fun1(..){..}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

buff[i] is a floating point number, use %f format specifier to print it. I.e. use:

```
printf("%f\n", buff[i]);
```

instead of

```
printf("%d\n", buff[i]);
```

Also you have not initialized your array to some values. It will contain (and print) random values.